# Translate ElasticSearch query to Nest c#

Tags: elasticsearch, translation, nest

I need some help in creating an AggregationDictionary from the following elasticsearch query

```
GET organisations/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_country": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "country"
        },
        "aggs": {
          "by_country2": {
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "country.isDisplayed": "true"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "aggs": {
              "by_country3": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "country.displayName.keyword",
                  "size": 9999
                }
              }   
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I managed to write this horrible piece of code which I am pretty sure it is wrong, I am totally new to this.

```
AggregationDictionary aggs = new AggregationDictionary()
{
  {
    "countries_step1",
    new NestedAggregation("countries_step1")
    {
      Path = "country",
      Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary()
      {
        {
          "countries_step2",
          new FilterAggregation("countries_step2")
          {
            Filter = new BoolQuery
            {
              Must = new QueryContainer[] {
                new NestedQuery
                {
                  Query = new TermQuery
                  {
                    Field = "country.isDisplayed",
                    Value = true
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary
            {
              {
                "countries_step3",
                new TermsAggregation("countries_step3")
                {
                  Field = "country.displayName.keyword",
                  Size = 9999
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Can someone tell me if I am in the correct direction? I am using Nest 6.6.0. Is there any tool that helps with these translations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have so far is pretty solid, but when you try to execute this aggregation with the following call

```
var searchAsync = await client.SearchAsync<Document>(s => s.Size(0).Aggregations(aggs));
```

you will get this error

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "query malformed, empty clause found at [14:22]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "query malformed, empty clause found at [14:22]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Checking request which was sent to elasticsearch give us the answer why it happened

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "countries_step1": {
      "aggs": {
        "countries_step2": {
          "aggs": {
            "countries_step3": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "country.displayName.keyword",
                "size": 9999
              }
            }
          },
          "filter": {}
        }
      },
      "nested": {
        "path": "country"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

filter clause is empty, this is because you tried to used nested query but you didn't pass [path parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html#nested-top-level-params). We don't need nested query here (as shown in your example query), we can simplify the whole query to

```
var aggs = new AggregationDictionary()
{
    {
        "countries_step1",
        new NestedAggregation("countries_step1")
        {
            Path = "country",
            Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary()
            {
                {
                    "countries_step2",
                    new FilterAggregation("countries_step2")
                    {
                        Filter = new BoolQuery
                        {
                            Must = new QueryContainer[]
                            {
                                new TermQuery
                                {
                                    Field = "country.isDisplayed",
                                    Value = true
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary
                        {
                            {
                                "countries_step3",
                                new TermsAggregation("countries_step3")
                                {
                                    Field = "country.displayName.keyword",
                                    Size = 9999
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now we have a valid request sent to elasticsearch.

There are a couple of things we can improve here:

**1. Remove unnecessary bool query**

```
Filter = new BoolQuery
{
    Must = new QueryContainer[]
    {
        new TermQuery
        {
            Field = "country.isDisplayed",
            Value = true
        }
    }
},
```

to

```
Filter =
    new TermQuery
    {
        Field = "country.isDisplayed",
        Value = true
    },
```

**2. Replace string field names**

Usually, when doing calls from .Net there is some kind of POCO type which is helping us with writing strongly-typed requests to elasticsearch which helps us managing clean code and refactoring. With this, we can change field definition from

```
"country.displayName.keyword"
```

to

```
Infer.Field<Document>(f => f.Country.FirstOrDefault().DisplayName.Suffix("keyword"))
```

my types definition

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Nested]
    public List<Country> Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public bool IsDisplayed { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

**3. Consider using a fluent syntax**

With NEST you can write queries in two ways: using object initializer syntax (which you did) or with help of fluent syntax. [Have a look](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/master/writing-queries.html). Trying to write above query with the fluent syntax you will get something like

```
var searchResponse = await client.SearchAsync<Document>(s => s
    .Size(0)
    .Aggregations(a => a.Nested("by_country", n => n
        .Path(p => p.Country)
        .Aggregations(aa => aa
            .Filter("by_country2", f => f
                .Filter(q => q
                    .Term(t => t
                        .Field(field => field.Country.FirstOrDefault().IsDisplayed)
                        .Value(true)))
                .Aggregations(aaa => aaa
                    .Terms("by_country3", t => t
                        .Field(field => field.Country.FirstOrDefault().DisplayName.Suffix("keyword"))
                        .Size(9999)
                    )))))));
```

which I find a little bit easier to follow and write, maybe it will be better for you as well.

As a final note, have a look into [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debugging.html) and check how you can debug your queries.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also check out the Writing aggregations docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-aggregations.html

Comment: the level of help on this site is extraordinary! can't thank you enough!